# Android hide and show components

Tags: java, android

I am making a sqlite android application which is to list some data , show graphs , visit a web site by starting default browser(not in application by using webview) , send emails by using a form . I will have a couple of forms . So what I was thinking is that instead of using several activities and xml layouts I put it all in one xml layout and simply on button click show and hide components as it is done with javascript 
These are my components for now ...

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="432dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="ENTER COMPANY NAME " />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp" 
        android:entries="@array/country_arrays"
        android:prompt="@string/country_prompt"
        />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1" 
        android:entries="@array/limit_arrays"
        android:prompt="@string/limit_prompt"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Hide" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Show" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Then I am to show or hide components by using for example

```
spinner1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
spinner1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

This seams to be working fine , but I am getting a kind of low on space on my xml screen. How do I put more components in the bottom and make my View scroll down although I have put

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

on the top of my xml layout . And is this a good idea for a menu organisation ?

Comment: I think the problem because of given a fixed height to Relative Layout..

Comment: Should I use wrap_content ?

Comment: yes you should....because of fixed height it might be problem.

Comment: But again it seams that Android sdk does not allow me  to put more components if I already have some of them on the screen , when I put  wrap_content it is limited to the height of all the components that were in layout , puts new components on top over other ones!?

Comment: In ScrollView you can't put more than one Layout..because it contains only one child view..